# Is it allowed to use Bootstrap like popular libraries in chrome extension pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to add [bootstap.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) and [bootstrap.bundle.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js) in **popup.html** of a Chrome extension so that it looks better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Popup</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Though I have some concerns;

1. Does Chrome Store allow using third-party libraries in the Chrome extension?
2. Can I use **minified** versions of library files or do I need to pack non-minified source files of the library? Does Chrome Store ask for the original source links of these files?
3. Can using **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** in **popup.html** context create security issues?
4. Does using these third-party libraries (with minified version files) delay the review of the extension on Chrome Store?